# java.net.BindException How can I clear the sockets or what ever is causing it?

Tags: java, networking, stream

I need some help with, I guess a simple networking related problem I'm having. It will also help me better understand how all this works by knowing what isn't being .close()'ed. I'm sure this is pretty simple, but for me its all very new. This is the client program. I can most likely append the server then, if I can figure this out. Thanks

```
    public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    static int start = 0;

    public static void start() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4567);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            //1) Take and echo input (In this case a message)
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String message = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message recieved from Client:" + message);
            //2) Response of client message
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            printWriter.println("Server echoing back the message ' " + message + " ' from Client");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("e " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        start++;

            clearUp();

        if (start < 5) {
            System.out.println("Closing binds and Restarting" + start);

            start();
        }
    }

    public void clearUp(){
        //How would I clear the stuff that is left bound
          so I can restart via start() and avoid the
          java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind ?
    }

}
```

How would I clear the stuff that is left bound so I can restart via start() and avoid java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind ?

Comment: Did you intend for `start` to invoke itself recursively?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: There are several major problems with the way this code is structured.  The primary issue is that you are not closing the server socket. I suggest you read one of the _many_ tutorials available describing socket programming in Java and apply the techniques described there.  Specifically, you need to open the server socket only once, and start a separate thread to handle each connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is within these lines.

```
public static void start() {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4567);
        //tells server to listen on 4567
 ....

if (start < 5) {
        System.out.println("Closing binds and Restarting" + start);

        start();
}
```

You are calling start over and over, and telling the ServerSocket to listen on the same port.

Instead, what you want to to do, is have one ServerSocket, held by the server to be listening. Then a regular Socket connects to the ServerSocket, and the Server `accepts` the connection, and this returns a new `Socket` for them to communicate on. Your question seems to indicate that this is the client code, and a tradational client should not have a ServerSocket, because it isn't listening on some port.

What you want to do is
Server:

1. Make serversocket on some port. Loop within.
2. Wait for connection from client
3. accept connection. This will cause a new socket to be created for you and the client to communicate on

Client:

1. connect to server socket
2. talk to it through the socket.

If this does not make sense, I can give some code examples.

Be warned, in order for your server to talk to multiple clients, you need to use threading.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are rebinding, so I have removed that bit.

You are also not closing any of your sockets.

They are resources so you should not rely on java cleaning them up properly by itself.

```
public static void start() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int exitCode = 0;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4567);
        while(start < 5){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            //1) Take and echo input (In this case a message)
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String message = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message recieved from Client:" + message);
            //2) Response of client message
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            printWriter.println("Server echoing back the message ' " + message + " ' from Client");
            // close resource
            socket.close();
            start++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("e " + e);
        exitCode = -1;
    } finally {
        if (serverSocket != null){
            try {
                // close server
                serverSocket .close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("e " + e);
            }
        }
    }
    if (exitCode != 0){
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```